# Printing value of mongoose result on console in express node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am getting value from mongoose through query

```
          console.log(docs);
output :  [ { usercount: 0, _id: 5653fab1d6b5f1cf624b97fd },
         { usercount: 1, _id: 56541b49d6b5f1cf624b97ff } ]

       console.log(docs[1]._id);
output:   56541b49d6b5f1cf624b97ff

      console.log(docs[1].usercount);
output: undefined
```

So, How i will get the value of usercount.

I have model uservisitcount.js with following code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  ,Schema = mongoose.Schema
  uservisitcountSchema = new Schema( {
      usercount:String,
  }),
Usercount = mongoose.model('uservisitcount', uservisitcountSchema);

module.exports = Usercount;
```

Included this model in controller with:

```
var Uservisitcount = require('../models/uservisitcount');
```

And i ran following query:

```
Uservisitcount.find({},function(err,docs){
       console.log(docs);
       console.log(docs[1]._id);
       console.log(docs[1].usercount);
   }
```

Comment: It seems that you are doing everything correctly. Is there any onther code that could affect docs array?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr: Please see edits i have done.

Comment: add a `console.log(docs[1]);`

Answer (score 1):

Apply `JSON.stringify()` on the returned data:

```
Uservisitcount.find({},function(err,docs){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(docs)); 
  // or: 
  console.log('%s', docs); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `mongoose` library for this example to execute

```bash
$ npm install mongoose
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// define a Mongoose schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   email: String,
   age: Number
});

// create a Mongoose model
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

// connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database', { useNewUrlParser: true });

// retrieve data from the User model and console log it
User.find({}, (err, users) => {
   if (err) {
       console.error(err);
   } else {
       console.log(users);
   }
});
```

will print first record with `index of 0` if you want specific recore using `users[]`

Example:-
`users[0].name` -- will print name
`users[0].email` -- will print email
`users[0].age` -- will print age